# Is there any method to abort cin or scanf

Tags: c++, multithreading, io

I have a multithreaded program in which on thread waits for input through a terminal and the other will get data from the socket. Is there any way to abort first threads cin/scanf to print in console data from second thread.

I think to kill the first thread, print data from second thread then run first thread again. But I'm looking for a better method, something like abort cin then reawoke it.

```
void thread1(){
    cin>>string;
    doSomething();
}
void thread2(){
    cout<<getSomeData();
}
```

In usual case, it won't print data till something would be entered from keyboard.

[EDIT]

I found a particular solution, like if it doesn't get input it will interrupt, everything was done in C style.
In any case if you are interested check "Head First C" book, section "Interprocess Communication: It's good to talk".

Comment: No, input through the standard library functions is blocking with no standard (from a C or C++ perspective) way of interrupting them. If you want "interruptable" input then you need to turn to the operating system and use some kind of non-blocking input mechanism, or polling for input (and interruption).

Comment: Sending a signal can be used to interrupt blocking system calls. I don't know how an implementation of `std::cin` handles that though i.e. whether it restarts, or returns in a fail/bad-state.

Comment: There is no standard C++ way, but may be platform specific ones. What is your platform?

Comment: Raspberry pi3 with raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's bit too late. After a while I was supposed to make cpp multithreaded application again and had the same problem. This time it was done with implementing non blocking input with stdio`s getch() and I think it fits to be the best solution.

Comment: I thought it would be nice to leave an sample here if later someone would like to reuse this part. https://github.com/GagMirz/movingShapes/blob/master/include/nonBlockingInput.cpp

Comment: Using ncurses is a non-standard, Unix-only solution.

Comment: @Chnossos yes I knew about ncurses, but still external library for only this one method which will work only on unix was not my best solution. I had an assessment and had to prepare something that will work on windows as well.

Comment: I commented this because your link points to a Unix-only solution. How did you do it on Windows then? Might be useful to edit your answer to provide the final solution here because your link might die someday.

Comment: Good point @Chnossos I'll later update here with code sample to be more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following solution is standard enough, but it works on both my Fedora Linux (GCC 10.3) & Windows 10 (MSVC 16.11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, [] (int s)
    {
        std::signal(s, SIG_DFL);
        std::fclose(stdin);
        std::cin.setstate(std::ios::badbit); // To differenciate from EOF input
    });

    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Input CTRL+C or EOF now!" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::cout << (std::cin.bad() ? "\rinterrupted" : "eof") << std::endl;
}
```

Don't ask me how to reuse `cin` from that state now.